# Segmentation fault trying to implement Prim's algorithm on file

Tags: c, prims-algorithm

I'm getting just `Segmentation Fault` from my code but it's not telling me where. I'm guessing it has to do with the file but I'm not entirely sure. That is the only thing keeping me from testing and debugging the rest of the code (if this implementation of Prim's actually works and if the file is being read properly). Feel free to ask questions. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10
#define INF INT_MAX
int spanning[N][N];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int prims(int amtrx[][N], int *n);
    void printpaths(int *n);

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Missing Filename.\n");
        return(1);
    } else if (argc > 2) {
        printf("Too many arguments.\n");
        return(1);
    }
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    int *n, *stv, i, j, nsz, nedg, fr, to, vtx, wt;
    vtx = 1111;
    nedg = 999;
    nsz = 100;
    stv = 0;
    n = 0;

    if(f) {
        fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &nsz, &nedg, &vtx);
        int amtrx[nsz][N];

        for(i = 0; i < nsz; i++){
                for(j = 0; j < nsz; j++){
                        amtrx[i][j] = INF;
                }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < nedg; i++){
            fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &fr, &to, &wt);
            amtrx[fr][to] = wt;
            amtrx[to][fr] = wt;
        }
        *n = nsz;
        *stv = vtx;

        int total_cost = prims(amtrx, n);
        printpaths(n);
        printf("\n\nTotal cost of spanning tree: %d", total_cost);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to open the file\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

int prims(int amtrx[][N], int *n) {
    int cost[N][N];
    int u, v, min_distance, distance[N], from[N];
    int visited[N], no_of_edges, i, min_cost, j;

    for(i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            if(amtrx[i][j] == 0)
                cost[i][j] = INF;
            else {
                cost[i][j] = amtrx[i][j];
                spanning[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    distance[0] = 0;
    visited[0] = 1;

    for(i = 1; i < *n; i++) {
        distance[i] = cost[0][i];
        from[i] = 0;
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    min_cost = 0;
    no_of_edges = *n - 1;

    while(no_of_edges > 0) {
        min_distance = INF;
        for(i = 1; i < *n ; i++)
            if(visited[i] == 0 && distance[i] < min_distance) {
                v = i;
                min_distance = distance[i];
            }

        u = from[v];

        spanning[u][v] = distance[v];
        spanning[v][u] = distance[v];
        no_of_edges--;
        visited[v] = 1;

        for(i = 1; i < *n; i++)
            if(visited[i] == 0 && cost[i][v] < distance[i]) {
                distance[i] = cost[i][v];
                from[i] = v;
            }
        min_cost = min_cost + cost[u][v];
    }
    return min_cost;
}

void printpaths(int *n) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < *n; j++)
            printf("%d\t", spanning[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Here is what is in the input file:

```
6 10 0 <-- size, edges, start
0 1 16 <-- from, to, weight
0 5 21
0 4 19
1 2 5
1 3 6
1 5 11
2 3 10
3 4 18
3 5 14
4 5 33
```

Comment: "it's not telling me where". You need to run your program in a debugger. It will tell you exactly where. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @kaylum an online debugger online told me nothing was wrong? And I am compiling the file that will treat every warning as an error, so the fact that it compiles means it's probably going to be hard to debug and I think that it needs a keen eye from someone who is more adept at C than me

Comment: I think you are confusing compiling with debugging. You really need to learn to debug effectively yourself. You can't rely on Stackoverflow to do all your debugging for you.

Comment: @kaylum I am just comparing. I've been working on this for a long time and could only turn to stackoverflow for help. Classes are online now and I've exhausted all other resources

Comment: What do you mean "comparing"? Do yo mean "compiling". That is a necessary but not sufficient step for getting a working program. As I said, highly recommend you learn to use a **debuggger**. That's not a compiler but a different tool like `gdb`.

Comment: @kaylum No, I don't. I have used gdb in the past. I am not very adept at it though. I was just hoping there might be an immediately noticeable problem with the code. Like I need to use `malloc()` on something. I can't learn everything about a debugger in one day. I haven't learned enough about it in school

Comment: Use a debugger. Really. One minute in a debugger will tell you exactly which line of code causes the seg fault. At a minimum you can report that back here. `int *n; n = 0; *n = nsz` is one problem.  You are using invalid pointers all over the place. `n` is a pointer and you set it to `0`. Then when you do `*n` you are basically doing `*0`. That is, dereferencing a NULL pointer. Same with `stv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kaylum said above. You should use the a debuggger when you see the `Segmentation Fault`. For me, i always try to run the program with `valgrind` when i see this fault. With `valgrind` (Use `-g` when you compile the code, firstly) you can see where is memory fault.

For your program, it figures out this line `*n = nsz;`. So look at the variable `n` and `nsz`.

Btw, you have to allocate for 2 varibale `n` and `stv` instead of assigning them to 0.

```
stv = malloc(sizeof(int));
n = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The result after allocating:

```
0   16  0   0   0   0   
16  0   5   6   0   11  
0   5   0   0   0   0   
0   6   0   0   18  0   
0   0   0   18  0   0   
0   11  0   0   0   0   

Total cost of spanning tree: 56
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I also ended up using `gdb` to find the location of the fault, so that was also super useful, thanks @kaylum

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with pointer and parameter understanding in C function. I suppose you declare n as pointer to int because you use `int *` in your function prototype.

First solution, declare n and stv as int, use them as integers and pass their address in the function call.

```
...
int n, stv, i, j, nsz, nedg, fr, to, vtx, wt;
...
n = nsz;
stv = vtx;

int total_cost = prims(amtrx, &n);
printpaths(&n);
```

But, in the `prims` and `printpaths` functions, you do not change the value of n, so you do not need pointer to n.

```
...
int n, stv, i, j, nsz, nedg, fr, to, vtx, wt;
...
n = nsz;
stv = vtx;

int total_cost = prims(amtrx, n);
printpaths(n);

...
int prims(int amtrx[][N], int n) {
    int cost[N][N];
    int u, v, min_distance, distance[N], from[N];
    int visited[N], no_of_edges, i, min_cost, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(amtrx[i][j] == 0)
                cost[i][j] = INF;
            else {
                cost[i][j] = amtrx[i][j];
                spanning[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

    distance[0] = 0;
    visited[0] = 1;

    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        distance[i] = cost[0][i];
        from[i] = 0;
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    min_cost = 0;
    no_of_edges = n - 1;

    while(no_of_edges > 0) {
        min_distance = INF;
        for(i = 1; i < n ; i++)
            if(visited[i] == 0 && distance[i] < min_distance) {
                v = i;
                min_distance = distance[i];
            }

        u = from[v];

        spanning[u][v] = distance[v];
        spanning[v][u] = distance[v];
        no_of_edges--;
        visited[v] = 1;

        for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if(visited[i] == 0 && cost[i][v] < distance[i]) {
                distance[i] = cost[i][v];
                from[i] = v;
            }
        min_cost = min_cost + cost[u][v];
    }
    return min_cost;
}

void printpaths(int n) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d\t", spanning[i][j]);
    }
}
```

To explain very briefly your error :

n is a pointer to int and you assign it to 0 (`n=0`). So it points to "zero" memory address. (Rq : too long to explain what "zero" memory address means that is why I use "" ). After, when you write `*n=nsz`, you try to write nsz value at this "zero" memory address that is forbidden. If you want to use pointer, you must allocate memory to store the value as Hitokiri suggested.